# Parse date time from string of format ddMMMyyyy hhmm (with Month-Name)

Tags: c#, string-parsing

I am kind of stuck with an issue where I am unable to to parse the date and time from a string, which I am reading from a text file. The string I am getting is in following format:

**05SEP1998 2400**

and I am trying to parse the string through the following code:

```
string dateTimeStr = "05SEP1998 2400"

var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

const string Format = "ddMMMyyyy hhmm";

var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeStr, Format, provider);
```

But while parsing, the above code throws a FormatException:

`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Could anybody please help me fixing this issue?

Comment: Yeah same error at my end for this code.

Comment: DateTime has only 23 hours not 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hh` is 12 hour, `HH` is 24 hour.  However, it must be in the range 0-23, not 24.  If you can't easily change how those date strings are generated, you can parse it manually:

```
string dateTimeStr = "05SEP1998 2400";

var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

const string Format = "ddMMMyyyy HHmm";
int HourPos = Format.IndexOf("HH");
var hour = dateTimeStr.Substring(HourPos, 2);
bool addDay = hour == "24";
if (addDay)
    dateTimeStr = dateTimeStr.Substring(0, HourPos) + "00" + dateTimeStr.Substring(HourPos + 2);
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeStr, Format, provider);
if (addDay)
    dateTime += TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
```

Note that this will throw exceptions if `dateTimeStr` doesn't have the right number of characters.  You might want to handle that better.

Comment: I find your approach wrong. Why? Because in this code for example `"05SEP1998 2400"` you assume that 24 is 0th Hour of 5th Sep. But Infact it is 0th Hour of 6th Sept. Hence realdate is `"06SEP1998 0000"`

Comment: That's why I have `dateTime += TimeSpan.FromHours(24);`.  The example date resolves to `9/6/1998 12:00:00 AM` (or `06SEP1998 0000`).

Answer (score 0):

There are 24 hours in a day. But while writing we say its from 0-23. It is giving exception on hours format.

**How I found out?**

I tried creating a `DateTime` object from your string like

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1998, 9, 5, 24, 0, 0);
```

It gave error on Hours that `Hour. minute and second parameters descrive an un-representable DateTime`